# Arrow link on footer not working

Tags: html, css

I have an arrow (a tag) on my footer with some :after and :before CSS customizations and I can't make it work well.
It's only clickable in some parts, not the entire arrow, I'm 100% sure that is because of the :after and :before selectors.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
footer {
  background-color: #239bd2;
  position: relative;
}
footer:before,
footer:after,
footer > .arrow {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #239bd2;
}
footer:after {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-width: 8px;
}
footer > .arrow {
  margin-left: -11px;
  border-width: 11px;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Mentions légales</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CGV</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Livraison</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Engagement Qualité</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Any way I can change my code to get the click efect working for the a tag properly?

Live website can be found [here](http://www.florin-pop.com/HOSMIUM/footer.html).

Comment: what exactly is your problem above. The footer link doesn't work?

Comment: The arrow link, you can see you hover over but the cursor is not changing

Comment: ahh so mean when hover the link the cursor changes to arrow? or you want to add an arrow to the link when hover by using css :after

Comment: No, you see the white arrow? I want it to be clickable, because it is an <a> tag. But it not clickable, only when you move above it. It should work like a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you have is the best setup, but yes, the `:before` and `:after` are 'in the way' of the click.

Try:

```
footer:before, footer:after{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: No, I want the have the click work. That will be used to move the user up to the top of the page. The problem is that when you click on that white arrow, it is not working, because it's hidden probably. Only when you move a bit above it will work the click.

Comment: Did you try my code? You can click the white arrow now that the before and after don't have click events. The main a tag is clickable. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waEzbz

Comment: No problem. I agree with @Andrew Staker about moving the pseudo elements, check the setup here: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: this solution might break some markup try moving out the pseudo elements or you might check my solution below @FlorinPop

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried placing the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements on the `.arrow` anchor tag instead?

Right now they're on the footer and are covering parts of the anchor tag.

Edit: I've reworked your styles a little.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
footer {
  background-color: #239bd2;
  position: relative;
}
footer > .arrow:before, footer > .arrow:after, footer > .arrow {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #239bd2;
}

footer > .arrow:before {
  margin-left: -11px;
  border-width: 11px;
  top: -2px;
  border-bottom-color: #FFF;
}

footer > .arrow:after {
  margin-left: -8px;
  border-width: 8px;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Mentions légales</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CGV</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Livraison</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Engagement Qualité</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I've tried but it messed up. Maybe I did it the wrong way. Can you show me how to do it please?

Answer (score 1):

You might try this solution.

Wrap the arrow inside the span tag and I move the anchor tag(link) outside the wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
  <!-- your :before arrow applies here -->
  <div id="arrow_wrap">
      <span class="arrow"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- your :after arrow here -->
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #arrow_wrap:before,
    #arrow_wrap:after,
    #arrow_wrap > .arrow {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -20px;
        border: 20px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #239bd2;
    }
    #arrow_wrap:after {
        margin-left: -8px;
        border-width: 8px;
    }
    #arrow_wrap > .arrow {
        margin-left: -11px;
        border-width: 11px;
        border-bottom-color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

A working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/owtck808/